# create different labels for different data chart js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

im trying to create different labels for different data

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {

  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels:['total','profit','income'],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'total price',
        data: [1000],
        backgroundColor:backgroundColorPrice,
        borderColor:borderColorPrice,
        borderWidth,
        fill
      },
      {
        label: 'total profit',
        data: [900],
        backgroundColor:backgroundColorProfit,
        borderColor:borderColorProfit,
        borderWidth,
        fill
      },  
      {
        label: 'total income',
        data: [1300],
        backgroundColor:backgroundColorIncome,
        borderColor:borderColorIncome,
        borderWidth,
        fill
      },             
    ]
},
  options: {
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: false
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<p class="mt-3 mx-auto md:text-2xl text-center  pb-3 ">charts</p>

<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

im trying to give each `labels` to each data , for example : total label for total price and profit label for total profit and so on
?! is it possible please
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on ikhvjs answer, if you set the `tooltip` mode to `point` it will only show the tooltip for the bar you are currently hovering and thus not show the zero values:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {

  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['total', 'profit', 'income'],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'total price',
        data: [1000, 0, 0],
        backgroundColor: "red",
        borderColor: "red",
      },
      {
        label: 'total profit',
        data: [0, 900, 0],
        backgroundColor: "blue",
        borderColor: "red",
      },
      {
        label: 'total income',
        data: [0, 0, 1300],
        backgroundColor: "green",
        borderColor: "red",
      },
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        mode: 'point',
        intersect: false
      },
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

<p class="mt-3 mx-auto md:text-2xl text-center  pb-3 ">charts</p>

<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {

  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels:['total','profit','income'],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'total price',
        data: [1000,0,0],
        backgroundColor:"red",
        borderColor:"red",
      },
      {
        label: 'total profit',
        data: [0,900,0],
        backgroundColor:"blue",
        borderColor:"red",
      },  
      {
        label: 'total income',
        data: [0,0,1300],
        backgroundColor:"green",
        borderColor:"red",
      },             
    ]
},
  options: {
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: false
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

<p class="mt-3 mx-auto md:text-2xl text-center  pb-3 ">charts</p>

<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: thank you , but it show 0 numbers in mouse over , isnt there a better way ?